# In WPF, how to override an Event Trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` with multiple buttons. I want all the buttons except one to trigger an animation when the user clicks on them, so in the `StackPanel.Triggers` I have added this code:

```
<StackPanel.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animationName}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</StackPanel.Triggers>
```

In the particular button I have added this code:

```
<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource anotherAnimation}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

When clicking the button, both animations begin, so it appears that the second `EventTrigger` is just added to the first one and not override it.

How can I override the first `EventTrigger` so only the second one will be triggered when clicking on that particular button?

**Note:** I need the answer to be in pure XAML without any code-behind involved.

---

**EDIT:** Here is the storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="animationName">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="PageFrame"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `x:Key` property for necessary buttons. For example:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animationName}" />
             </EventTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">Styles are cool!</Button>
       <Button>No Animation:)</Button>
       <Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">Yes to animation!</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Update:**

If you want to avoid use `Style` just for a few buttons, just create Style for all `Button` controls and set `Style="{x:Null}"` to controls where you want to avoid animation. See the following example:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
       <!--This style will be applied to all Buttons, except where Style="{x:Null}"-->
       <Style TargetType="Button">
          <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="animationName">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources> 
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animationName}" />
             </EventTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Button Content="Yes to Animation"/>
      <Button Content="No Animation:)" Style="{x:Null}"/>
      <Button Content="Yes to Animation"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Update 1:**

*you have deleted the TargetName, but I really need to set it so the animation will be applied to the correct element.*

Since a style can be reused in multiple places in a WPF application, we can't reference to a UIElement from within the style. This behavior is by design.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice Idea. But, since I have A LOT of buttons, it's really annoying to write the `Style` attribute for each.  Is there a way to make it more general and not for each and every one of the buttons? Thank a Lot!

Comment: @Ruben - could you please demonstrate in an answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, it will not work for me is because the storyboard has a TargeName, so it cannot be in a style I think...

Comment: @StepUp - I have seen your update and IT IS AWESOME. I have updated the post so it contains the `Storyboard`. The problem is that because the `Storyboard` has a `TargetName` it cannot be in a style.

Comment: @StepUp Thanks. Still getting an error: "A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName 'PageFrame'."

Comment: @Sipo please, see my updated answer. I've tested it. It works perfectly:).

Comment: @StepUp - So sorry for being annoying but you have deleted the `TargetName`, but I really need to set it so the animation will be applied to the correct element. I thank you so very much for your time and your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108405/discussion-between-sipo-and-stepup).

Answer (score 2):

As promised I took @RayBurns answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764415/how-to-give-the-condition-for-eventtrigger) and modified it, to answer your question. The ConditionalEventTrigger is now looking like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Trigger
{
[ContentProperty("Actions")]
public class ConditionalEventTrigger : FrameworkContentElement
{
    private static readonly RoutedEvent TriggerActionsEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(EventHandler), typeof(ConditionalEventTrigger));
    public RoutedEvent RoutedEvent { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExcludedSourceNamesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ExcludedSourceNames", typeof (List<string>), typeof (ConditionalEventTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));

    public List<string> ExcludedSourceNames
    {
        get { return (List<string>) GetValue(ExcludedSourceNamesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExcludedSourceNamesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Actions", typeof (List<TriggerAction>), typeof (ConditionalEventTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(new List<TriggerAction>()));

    public List<TriggerAction> Actions
    {
        get { return (List<TriggerAction>) GetValue(ActionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActionsProperty, value); }
    }

    // "Triggers" attached property
    public static ConditionalEventTriggerCollection GetTriggers(DependencyObject obj) { return (ConditionalEventTriggerCollection)obj.GetValue(TriggersProperty); }
    public static void SetTriggers(DependencyObject obj, ConditionalEventTriggerCollection value) { obj.SetValue(TriggersProperty, value); }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggersProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Triggers", typeof(ConditionalEventTriggerCollection), typeof(ConditionalEventTrigger), new PropertyMetadata
    {
        PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
        {
            // When "Triggers" is set, register handlers for each trigger in the list 
            var element = (FrameworkElement)obj;
            var triggers = (List<ConditionalEventTrigger>)e.NewValue;
            foreach (var trigger in triggers)
                element.AddHandler(trigger.RoutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((obj2, e2) =>
                  trigger.OnRoutedEvent(element, e2)));
        }
    });



    // When an event fires, check the condition and if it is true fire the actions 
    void OnRoutedEvent(FrameworkElement element, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var originalSender = args.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        if(originalSender == null) return;
        DataContext = element.DataContext;  // Allow data binding to access element properties
        if (!ExcludedSourceNames.Any(x=>x.Equals(originalSender.Name)))
        {
            // Construct an EventTrigger containing the actions, then trigger it 
            var dummyTrigger = new EventTrigger { RoutedEvent = TriggerActionsEvent };
            foreach (var action in Actions)
                dummyTrigger.Actions.Add(action);

            element.Triggers.Add(dummyTrigger);
            try
            {
                element.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(TriggerActionsEvent));
            }
            finally
            {
                element.Triggers.Remove(dummyTrigger);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ConditionalEventTriggerCollection: List<ConditionalEventTrigger>{}
}
```

It can be used in your XAML like this. Take care that all SourceNames you don´t want to be recognized on execution of your actions are inside the `ExcludedSourceNames` section.:

```
        <trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.Triggers>
        <trigger:ConditionalEventTriggerCollection>
            <trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.ExcludedSourceNames>
                    <system:String>buttonTriggeringAnotherAnimation</system:String>
                </trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.ExcludedSourceNames>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"></BeginStoryboard>
            </trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger>
        </trigger:ConditionalEventTriggerCollection>
    </trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.Triggers>
```

To give you an ready to start example here is a window:

```
<Window x:Class="ConditionalEventTriggerExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConditionalEventTriggerExample"
    xmlns:trigger="clr-namespace:Trigger;assembly=Trigger"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FF5151FD"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FFFF7400"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="buttonTriggeringAnotherAnimation">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard2}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
    <trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.Triggers>
        <trigger:ConditionalEventTriggerCollection>
            <trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.ExcludedSourceNames>
                    <system:String>buttonTriggeringAnotherAnimation</system:String>
                </trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.ExcludedSourceNames>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"></BeginStoryboard>
            </trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger>
        </trigger:ConditionalEventTriggerCollection>
    </trigger:ConditionalEventTrigger.Triggers>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonTriggeringAnotherAnimation" Content="triggering another animation"/>
    <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button"/>
    <Button x:Name="button4" Content="Button"/>
    <Button x:Name="button5" Content="Button"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you don´t get it to work I can upload the solution on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, but I really need a more simple answer with no code-behind. Thank you so much for your time and investment!

Comment: That´s not codebehind. That´s a standalone class that enables the functionality of the ConditionalEventTrigger. You can place that class wherever you want, as long as you reference it correct in your XAML namespace section...

Comment: Ok, I will try it and if it works better I will choose this answer! Thanks!